# How to specify the console as a file to write on with ostream?

Tags: c++, file-io

**cout** is an object of the **ostream** class.
Also, when we write:

```
filebuf   objFileBuf;
objFileBuf.open ("test.txt", ios :: out);

ostream objOstream (&objFileBuf);
objOstream << "Test sentence\n";

objFileBuf.close();
```

the text gets written to the file.

How to specify the "console" as a file to write through ostream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ostream objOstream (cout.rdbuf());
objOstream << "Test sentence goes to console\n";
```

Or you can do this:

```
ostream & objOstream = cout;
objOstream << "Test sentence goes to console\n";
```

The second one doesn't work with streambuf, rather you just create a reference to the `std::cout`, and use the reference.

Comment: :) Thanks, but it is `rdbuf` not `rdbug`. anyway, that means we have to use cout indirectly? Then how does qdebug write to console?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You simply write to `cout` or `cerr`. These streams are arranged for by the shell and you cannot make more - you can't have your program make a new channel to the console. Why can't you use `cout` or `cerr`?

Comment: Doesn't qDebug write to the stream? If it can do it why can't I?

Comment: Presumably it just writes to `cerr`. You could test this by redirecting standard output and standard error to files or something else and then using qdebug. qdebug would presumably then output to wherever standard error is, because it simply access std::cerr unless it is explicitly given a file handle or string.

Comment: Presumably, he's testing his file-writing program. It's why I dug this up, anyway.